# text next to pagination

Tags: javascript, pagination

I am using onepage-scroll on my website here and I want to add text next to the pagination (the little bullet list). I know where I should add the text but it just displays the same text next to all the "bullet points", so it's not really useful. Do I need to create some kind of array it walks through to display the name for each "bullet point"?

Here is the code the ,array' must be added to:

```
if(settings.pagination == true) {
    paginationList += " <li><a data-index='"+(i+1)+"' href='#" + (i+1) + "'><p>TEXT MUST BE ADDED HERE</p></a></li>"
}
});
```

Comment: what text you want to add ? the number of the page ?

Comment: please post your html code

Comment: I want to add the text of the section e.g " Home "  or " Acts "